# How to use a scala.swing.Applet in a Scala Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scala, applet

I try to port some Java code to Scala.

I want to display a `scala.swing.Applet` in a GUI application.

With Java Swing I would do

```
val jframe = new JFrame()
jframe.add(APPLET)

jframe.setVisible(true)
APPLET.setFocusCycleRoot(true)

APPLET.init()
APPLET.start()
```

But code using Scala Swing

```
def top = new MainFrame {
  contents = APPLET
}
```

doesn't like the type:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.swing.Applet
required: scala.swing.Component
contents = APPLET
```

When I try to add the Applet via the Java peers, it fails like this:

```
def top = new MainFrame {
  contents = new Panel() {
    peer.add(new SinglePlayerGame)
  }
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.swing.Applet cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComponent
    at scala.swing.Container$Wrapper$$anon$1.componentAdded(Container.scala:43)
    at java.awt.Container.processContainerEvent(Container.java:2071)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2042)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1081)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:373)
```

How am I supposed to solve that problem?

Comment: `found   : scala.swihg.Applet`  What is a `swihg`?  Is it similar to a swig with a hiccup in the middle?  If that is a typo., I suggest copy/paste for I/O.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379901/scala-applets-simpleapplet-demo

Answer (score 3):

It's not written in Scala, but [`Subway`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway) is a simple example of a hybrid applet and application. Both `JApplet` and `JFrame` are [top-level containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), and `initContainer()` performs the common initialization.

Note that both components require proper attention to [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).